# Center Div with padding instead of margin

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a full width tab navbar with a bottom border, and I want to center the tabs horizontally.

The thing is, I can't do it with "margin: auto" because I want the bottom border to be full width. Is there any other way to center this, with padding maybe?

Also, I can't add any other divs inside "nav-tabs" due to the plugin I'm using for mobile support, so faking a border isn't really an option.

Here's the link: http://www.os-os.co.uk/CGMATHEWS/

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you center your menu-items using `text-align: center`? This will preserve the full-width border as well as center the nav-tabs; here's a solution, please add the following CSS at the bottom of your stylesheet:

```
.nav-tabs>li {
     float: none;
     display: inline-block;
}

.nav-tabs {
     text-align: center;
}
```

Here's a screenshot of how the nav-bar would look after adding the above CSS:

[image]

Comment: that did it! thanks a lot! after dealing with css for a long time I still manage to get stuck with such simple stuff.